# How to deactivate all python ports

Tags: macports, macos, python, package-management

I just started using enthought's canopy to manage my python packages; thus I want to disable and/or uninstall all of my macports python packages.  Nominally, I'd like to deactivate them first - make sure things still work - then uninstall and delete them.

I've tried doing:

```
sudo port deactivate py-*
```

but that returns the error:

```
Error: port deactivate failed: Image error: port py-abjad is not active.
```

I've tried to uninstall all inactive ports (`sudo port uninstall inactive`), but that didn't seem to resolve the issue.

Finally, if I try

```
sudo port deactivate active py-*
```

that just starts to deactivate everything...

---

edit:  e.g.

```
sudo port deactivate active py-*
--->  Deactivating py27-pygtk @2.24.0_1+x11
--->  Cleaning py27-pygtk
--->  Deactivating libglade2 @2.6.4_7
--->  Cleaning libglade2
--->  Deactivating gtk2 @2.24.22_0+x11
--->  Cleaning gtk2
--->  Deactivating atk @2.10.0_0
--->  Cleaning atk
--->  Deactivating autoconf @2.69_2
--->  Cleaning autoconf
--->  Deactivating automake @1.14_0
--->  Cleaning automake
--->  Deactivating bash @4.2.45_2
--->  Cleaning bash
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo port deactivate py-* and active` should do what you want. Note that py-* packages in MacPorts are usually just placeholders for the versioned ports, e.g. py27-*, so you might want to deactivate those, too.